# Changing localhost:9002 for exposing API

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to get the api working on an Azure VM. The url won't be `https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/ext/basestores/ext` anymore, but `otherUrl:9002/rest/v2/ext/basestores/ext`.

Could somebody tell me where to look for that?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got your question correctly, but at least from Spartacus point of view, you can define `backend.occ.baseUrl` configuration to any URL you need.

Here is the basic example:

```
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
   backend: {
     occ: {
       baseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002',
       prefix: '/rest/v2/'
     }
   },
 }),
```

And here are docs how to set-up Spartacus:
https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/building-the-spartacus-storefront-from-libraries/#adding-import-declarations-and-storefront-configuration-settings

Comment: Additionally, please be aware that when there's no `baseUrl` configured, the backend URLs will be relative to the application host. 

Most likely you did not provide a configuration for the baseUrl. If you do have this configuration in a local development, you might have used an environment specific configuration; the development build would pick up the baseUrl configuration from the standard `environment.ts` file, while for a `--prod` build, the configuration in the `environment.prod.ts` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with *hybris*. In your *hosts* file add an entry-

> 127.0.0.1    otherUrl